# Certificate and CSR md5 hash matches but both contains completely different domains

Tags: openssl, md5, x509certificate, x509, csr

I have a CSR and certificate which have entirely different subdomains in SAN, but hash of both these matches. Is this possible?

Trying below commands to check the hash:

```
openssl req -noout -modulus -in csrs.csr | openssl md5
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in cert.crt | openssl md5
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a CSR and certificate which have entirely different subdomains in SAN, but hash of both these matches. Is this possible?

As described, no.  A CSR and a certificate have completely different structure, so they won't end up with the same hash even when they're related.  Unless you're just hashing a common subset.

> openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in cert.crt

The output of that command is just something like

> Modulus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

which you'll note doesn't contain anything like the SAN.  Since you're now just comparing "do they agree on an RSA modulus value", sure the hashes can align.  The CA has no requirement to issue a certificate that uses the same SAN list as you request (the only thing that has to match is the public key).

> openssl md5

Of course, if you're using a broken algorithm, hash collisions could also pop up unexpectedly.  But, in this case, it's because you've thrown away 80% of both files and the remaining 20% are byte-for-byte equal, therefore produce the same hash.